# SQL Server, LINQ-to-SQL and representing multiple components in a container class

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, linq-to-sql, database-design

This question is in two parts:

**A)** Is my design wrong? If so, what would be the proper way to do this?

**B)** If my design is right, how do I implement it?

I have a data class that consists of multiple instances of a component class. An abstraction of the class structure would be this:
[image: Class Diagram]

In this example I have only two components in the container but in reality I have more. It's also important to point out that `Container` cares about which `Component` is which - they can't just be a list, they have individual names and meaning to the `Container`.

I've implemented the following structure in MS SQL Server 2008 to store this data:

```
CREATE TABLE Containers (
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  ComponentA int NULL,
  ComponentB int NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Containers PRIMARY KEY (ID));


CREATE TABLE Components (
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  Foo nchar(10) NOT NULL,
  Bar nchar(10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Components PRIMARY KEY (ID));


ALTER TABLE Containers
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ComponentA
  FOREIGN KEY (ComponentA)
  REFERENCES Components(ID);

ALTER TABLE Containers
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ComponentB
  FOREIGN KEY (ComponentB)
  REFERENCES Components(ID);
```

This already has a few drawbacks:

- In my model, components are unique, and can only belong to one property on one Container. In the DB, I have to enforce this manually.
- When a Container is deleted, the Components it references should also be deleted. This I have to do manually in the DB (with a trigger).

**The big problem, however, is this:**

I use LINQ-TO-SQL for my database access in the C# WPF MVVM desktop application I am building in Visual Studio 2010. When I pull the database tables above into the LINQ-TO-SQL designer, this is what I get:

[image: LINQ-TO-SQL Diagram]

I can manually set the relationships to One-to-One in the LING-TO-SQL designer, to stop the `Component` instances from having sets of type `Container`.
Correctly, each `Container` has two `Component` references. **However, the `Component` instances still have two `Container` references, where my model requires them to have only one.**

How can I implement my class design in SQL Server **or** how can I convince LINQ-to-SQL to interpret my database the way I intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A container has many components, but needs to reference them by name. You need a relationship table from container to component (in pseudo-sql):

```
create table ContainerComponents (
  ContainerID int FK references Container(ID),
  ComponentID int FK references Component(ID),
  Name string,
  -- optional - to give the relationship a meaning
  Type int FK references RelationshipType(ID)
)
```

To answer this question:

> In my model, components are unique, and can only belong to one property on one Container. In the DB, I have to enforce this manually.

Just create a unique constraint in `ContainerComponents` for `ContainerID` and `ComponentID`.

And this one:

> When a Container is deleted, the Components it references should also be deleted. This I have to do manually in the DB (with a trigger).

Use cascade deletes from `Container` to `ContainerComponents` to `Component`.

Comment: How would I cascade the delete from `ContainerComponents` to `Component`, since `Component` is the parent table in that foreign key relationship?

Comment: @Harikawashi: Yes you're right, I don't think you can do that. Maybe you could use a trigger in that case.